# Why the Output is the "full" array?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
char *array = "test";
cout << &array[0];
```

The output is test. Why is this working?

Comment: `char *array = "test";` should fail to compile.  The code should be `char const* array = "test";`

Answer (score 1):

`array[0]` is a single `char`.

`&array[0]` is a pointer to that single `char`. Its type is `char*`. And that type is used to mean "pointer to first `char` of null-terminated string". Which is how the stream output operator `<<` treats it.

If you want to print the pointer you need to cast it:

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&array[0)];
```

---

With that said, the definition

```
char *array = "test";
```

is wrong. Literal strings like `"test"` are *constant* arrays of characters (including the null-terminator).

So pointers needs to be `const` qualified:

```
const char *array = "test";
```

And the cast need to include a `const` as well.